# log4net set logging of two files with a different level logging from c# code

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

This is my problem, i want to log in 2 different files (one for error and one for ordinary information) by c# application and log4net, i found the configuration in xml, but i want to do it from code, this is the source that i found for the setting the logging of one file:

```
 public static void Setup()
    {

        Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
        hierarchy.Root.RemoveAllAppenders();

        PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();

        patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%date THREAD [%thread] %logger: %message%newline"; //%-5level
        patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

        RollingFileAppender infoRoller = new RollingFileAppender();

        infoRoller.AppendToFile = true;
        infoRoller.File = @"logs\";
        infoRoller.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Date;
        infoRoller.MaxSizeRollBackups = 3;
        infoRoller.Layout = patternLayout;
        infoRoller.DatePattern = @"IN\FO\_yyyy-MM-dd.\lo\g";
        infoRoller.StaticLogFileName = false;

        infoRoller.ActivateOptions();

        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(infoRoller);

        MemoryAppender memory = new MemoryAppender();

        memory.ActivateOptions();
        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(memory);

        hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.Debug;
        hierarchy.Configured = true;
    }
```

in another class for the logging:

```
private readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("GENERAL-LOG");
```

and

```
Logger.Setup();
log.Debug("Configurazioni caricate con successo.");
```

the code works.

now, i did this change to get 2 log:

```
    public static void Setup()
    {

        Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
        hierarchy.Root.RemoveAllAppenders();

        PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();

        patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%date THREAD [%thread] %logger: %message%newline"; //%-5level
        patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

        RollingFileAppender infoRoller = new RollingFileAppender();

        infoRoller.AppendToFile = true;
        infoRoller.File = @"logs\";
        infoRoller.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Date;
        infoRoller.MaxSizeRollBackups = 3;
        infoRoller.Layout = patternLayout;
        infoRoller.DatePattern = @"IN\FO\_yyyy-MM-dd.\lo\g";
        infoRoller.StaticLogFileName = false;

        infoRoller.ActivateOptions();
        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(infoRoller);

        //ADDED CODE
        RollingFileAppender errorRoller = new RollingFileAppender();

        errorRoller.AppendToFile = true;
        errorRoller.File = @"logs\";
        errorRoller.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Date;
        errorRoller.MaxSizeRollBackups = 3;
        errorRoller.Layout = patternLayout;
        errorRoller.DatePattern = @"ERROR_yyyy-MM-dd.\lo\g";
        errorRoller.StaticLogFileName = false;

        errorRoller.ActivateOptions();
        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(errorRoller);

        MemoryAppender memory = new MemoryAppender();

        memory.ActivateOptions();
        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(memory);

        hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.Debug;
        hierarchy.Configured = true;
    }

}
```

from other class:

```
    private readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("GENERAL-LOG");
    private readonly ILog elog = LogManager.GetLogger("ERROR-LOG");

    Logger.Setup();
    log.Debug("prova scrittura in file1");
    elog.Error("prova errore scrittura in file2");
```

result: both log files are written with the two messages.

Please kindly suggest, many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you have appended both appenders to the "root" logger. If you want to have two loggers then you must append them to specific loggers.

There I have commented the `hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(errorRoller);` and `hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(infoRoller);` since it is no longer required as appenders are appended to relevant loggers instead of the root.

Find the code below. There I have passed log and elog as parameters to the method and append the relevant appenders respectively.

```
   private static void Setup2(ILog infoLog, ILog elog)
    {
        Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
        hierarchy.Root.RemoveAllAppenders();

        PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();

        patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%date THREAD [%thread] %logger: %message%newline"; //%-5level
        patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

        RollingFileAppender infoRoller = new RollingFileAppender();

        infoRoller.AppendToFile = true;
        infoRoller.File = @"logs\";
        infoRoller.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Date;
        infoRoller.MaxSizeRollBackups = 3;
        infoRoller.Layout = patternLayout;
        infoRoller.DatePattern = @"IN\FO\_yyyy-MM-dd.\lo\g";
        infoRoller.StaticLogFileName = false;
        infoRoller.ActivateOptions();
        //   hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(infoRoller); //Not appended to the root logger anymore

        //ADDED CODE
        RollingFileAppender errorRoller = new RollingFileAppender();

        errorRoller.AppendToFile = true;
        errorRoller.File = @"logs\";
        errorRoller.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Date;
        errorRoller.MaxSizeRollBackups = 3;
        errorRoller.Layout = patternLayout;
        errorRoller.DatePattern = @"ERROR_yyyy-MM-dd.\lo\g";
        errorRoller.StaticLogFileName = false;
        errorRoller.ActivateOptions();
        //   hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(errorRoller); //Not appended to the root logger anymore

        MemoryAppender memory = new MemoryAppender();

        memory.ActivateOptions();
        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(memory);
        hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.Debug;
        hierarchy.Configured = true;

        ILog log = infoLog;
        Logger logger = (Logger)log.Logger;
        logger.AddAppender(errorRoller);

        log = elog;
        logger = (Logger)log.Logger;
        logger.AddAppender(infoRoller);
    }
```

Invoking the method

```
    private readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("GENERAL-LOG");
    private readonly ILog elog = LogManager.GetLogger("ERROR-LOG");

    Logger.Setup2(log,elog);
    log.Debug("prova scrittura in file1");
    elog.Error("prova errore scrittura in file2");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, however the compiler write this error: 'Logger' does not contain a definition for 'AddAppender' and no extension method 'AddAppender' accepting a first argument of type 'Logger' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I think the problem is you have named the class which has Setup2() method as Logger  and intellisense refers that class instead of the log4net Logger.  Rename your class to something and try the solution. The above works fine for me since my invoking class name is not Logger.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace Setup() method related code block with below code block.

Changes:
1. Removed "hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(infoRoller);" and commented "hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(errorRoller);".
2. Removed "MemoryAppender" as seems that is not required in your case.

```
public static void Setup()
        {


            Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
            hierarchy.Root.RemoveAllAppenders();

            PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();

            patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%date THREAD [%thread] %logger: %message%newline"; //%-5level
            patternLayout.ActivateOptions();


            ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("GENERAL-LOG");
            Logger l = (Logger)log.Logger;

            RollingFileAppender infoRoller = new RollingFileAppender();

            infoRoller.AppendToFile = true;
            infoRoller.File = @"logs\";
            infoRoller.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Date;
            infoRoller.MaxSizeRollBackups = 3;
            infoRoller.Layout = patternLayout;
            infoRoller.DatePattern = @"IN\FO\_yyyy-MM-dd.\lo\g";
            infoRoller.StaticLogFileName = false;
            infoRoller.ActivateOptions();

            l.AddAppender(infoRoller);


            //ADDED CODE

            ILog elog = LogManager.GetLogger("ERROR-LOG");
            Logger el = (Logger)elog.Logger;


            RollingFileAppender errorRoller = new RollingFileAppender();

            errorRoller.AppendToFile = true;
            errorRoller.File = @"logs\";
            errorRoller.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Date;
            errorRoller.MaxSizeRollBackups = 3;
            errorRoller.Layout = patternLayout;
            errorRoller.DatePattern = @"ERROR_yyyy-MM-dd.\lo\g";
            errorRoller.StaticLogFileName = false;

            errorRoller.ActivateOptions();

            el.AddAppender(errorRoller);
            //hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(errorRoller);

            MemoryAppender memory = new MemoryAppender();

            memory.ActivateOptions();
            hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(memory);
            hierarchy.Configured = true;
        }
```

Hope this will help you.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your advice!